# TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'ShowBookedId')

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to add data in BookedMovie object, but it gives me this error:

> TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'ShowBookedId')

I don't know how can I resolve it. Please help me.

BookingInterface

```js
export interface Booking 
{   
    Ticket:Number;
    ShowTime:Time;
    ShowBookedId:Number;
    MovieBookedId:Number;
    UserId:Number;
}
```

Booking.component.ts

```js
BookedMovie !: Booking

bookingmovie()
{
    const movie = this.bookingform.value;
    let decoded : any = (jwt_decode(this.token));

    console.log(decoded);

    this.BookedMovie.ShowBookedId = this.moviedata.shows.id;
    this.BookedMovie.MovieBookedId = this.moviedata.id;
    this.BookedMovie.UserId = decoded.UserId;
    this.BookedMovie.Ticket = movie.ticket;

    console.log(this.BookedMovie);

    this.movieservice.AddMovieBooking(this.BookedMovie).subscribe
    (
      response =>
      {
        console.log(response);
        this.submitted = true;
        alert("Movie Booked");
        this.bookingform.reset();
      }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
BookedMovie !: Booking
```

```js
this.BookedMovie.ShowBookedId = this.moviedata.shows.id;
this.BookedMovie.MovieBookedId = this.moviedata.id;
this.BookedMovie.UserId = decoded.UserId;
this.BookedMovie.Ticket = movie.ticket;
```

From above, you didn't create an instance or initialize with a value for `BookedMovie`.

Create an instance / assign the value for `BookedMovie` as below:

```js
this.BookedMovie = {
  ShowBookedId: this.moviedata.shows.id,
  MovieBookedId: this.moviedata.id,
  UserId: decoded.UserId,
  Ticket: movie.ticket,
  ShowTime: /* value */
};
```